# Beginner: Can't decode this assembly code

Tags: assembly, stack, 64-bit, cpu-registers

I'm really new to assembly language, and I'm trying to decode an assembly file generated from a binary (with gdb).  I'm having trouble understanding the following code (this is the start of a new function).  I am on an x64 machine and `%rdi` holds 6 digits (my input).  So let's just say that's `0 1 2 3 4 5`)

```
   400e79:       55                      push   %rbp
   400e7a:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   400e7d:       48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
   400e81:       48 89 7d d8             mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)
   400e85:       48 8d 75 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rsi
   400e89:       48 8b 7d d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdi
```

If I may, I want to show you what I THINK is going on:

`400e79`: So when we start a function, we push the old base pointer onto the stack.  So the stack looks like:

```
 RETURN ADDRESS
 old %rbp value  <--- %rsp
```

`400e7a`: Stack looks like:

```
 RETURN ADDRESS
 old %rbp value <---- %rsp, %rbp
```

`400e7d`:  Stack looks like:

```
 RETURN ADDRESS
 old %rbp value  <----%rbp
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----  <---%rsp
```

`400e81`: The stuff from here is what's really confusing me.  We are moving what's in `%rdi` (`0 1 2 3 4 5`) into `-0x28(%rbp)`.  So the stack looks like:

```
 RETURN ADDRESS
 old %rbp value  <----%rbp
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 ----empty----  <---%rsp
```

However, when I try to see what's in `-0x28(%rbp)` by running `x/s $rbp-0x28` on gdb, I don't get `0 1 2 3 4 5` as I'd expect, but I get `"\020C"`.  Am I running this correctly?

`400e85:` Stack:

```
 RETURN ADDRESS
 old %rbp value  <----%rbp
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty----
 ----empty---- <--- %rsi
 0 1 2 3 4 5
 ----empty----  <---%rsp
```

`400e89:` I don't understand this at all.  We just did `mov    %rdi,-0x28(%rbp)` earlier, why are we now doing `mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdi`?  Isn't this repetitive?

Thanks a lot! I know this is really long, I appreciate your time helping me out!

Comment: What do you mean `rdi` holds your input? What is your "input"? Is "012345" a string? Is it a hex value, 0x012345?

Comment: It's what I type when I start the program. I type it as `0 1 2 3 4 5` with a space between each number.  It's a string (I think).

Comment: A pointer to an array of strings, then?

Comment: array of characters?  Sorry...I am not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.

The reason you get a weird result when you run `x/s $rbp-0x28` is that you can't put a string in a register. The value the register contains is most likely a pointer to that string, which means you need another level of indirection to read it. I believe this will work:

```
p/x *(char**)($rbp-0x28)
x/s $
```

As for the useless load, that is common for code which has been compiled without optimization. The compiler blindly converts each line to assembly without considering the current register values. I have seen code which passed a single value through several registers back to the register it was originally in.